# R - loop through a dataframe and print results by column names

Tags: r, loops, shiny, printing

I have this dataframe :

```
id  station  count
1   CL5       5
2   CL8       10
3   CL12      4
4   CL15      9
```

With a loop, I'd like to print this kind of message :

```
Station CL5 has 5 results
Station CL8 has 10 results
Station CL12 has 4 results
Station CL15 has 9 results
```

How could I do to loop and print these results by specify the column names I want to use (that is to say "station" and "count" in this example) ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `glue_data`

```
library(glue)
glue_data(df1, "Station {station} has {count} results")
```

-output

```
Station CL5 has 5 results
Station CL8 has 10 results
Station CL12 has 4 results
Station CL15 has 9 results
```

---

Or in a `for` loop in `base R`

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1))) 
  cat("Station", df1$station[i], "has", df1$count[i], "results\n")
```

-output

```
Station CL5 has 5 results
Station CL8 has 10 results
Station CL12 has 4 results
Station CL15 has 9 results
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, station = c("CL5", "CL8", "CL12", "CL15"
), count = c(5L, 10L, 4L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Just tried it, that's perfect ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to akrun's excellent answer, I would do the following avoiding explicit `for` loops, but using `apply` to process by row:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:4, station = c("CL5", "CL8", "CL12", "CL15"),
      count = c(5, 10, 4, 9))

apply(df[c("station", "count")], 1, function(i) {
  paste0("Station ", i[1], " has ", i[2], " results")
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

The output is a `list`:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Station CL5 has  5 results"

[[2]]
[1] "Station CL8 has 10 results"

[[3]]
[1] "Station CL12 has  4 results"

[[4]]
[1] "Station CL15 has  9 results"
```

If you want the output as a `data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame(cbind(apply(df[c("station", "count")], 1, function(i) {
  paste0("Station ", i[1], " has ", i[2], " results")
}, simplify = FALSE)))
```

Output:

```
                           V1
1  Station CL5 has  5 results
2  Station CL8 has 10 results
3 Station CL12 has  4 results
4 Station CL15 has  9 results
```